# Prevent Jsconfig.json from being created on launch of VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code, web-component, salesforce-lightning

I do development for salesforce and the LWC that we use is JS so recently like in the last month or two VS Code started auto including the jsconfig.json file in my LWC folder when i open a project.
The issue her is that the plugin i use to push the code to the cloud crashes when i push and that file is there.
Is there anyway to prevent the file from being created with crippling the JS functions of VScode.

Comment: Maybe contact the author of the plugin you do not name...

Comment: It's the Salesforce Extension Pack. I already logged a bug but I figured it was easier to have VS code not create the jsconfig.json file. Since it wasn't doing it before.

Comment: VScode does not create that file in my env. So its most likely another plugin